# Subquery issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to fetch the top 3 scores of unique players in the last n months. While I try to execute the query I am getting an error:

**Unknown column 'f.SC_Date' in 'where clause'**

Below is my query

```
SELECT * from   scores f
WHERE
  SC_Id IN (
          SELECT SC_Id FROM (
                  SELECT SC_Id from scores where DATE_FORMAT( SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) = DATE_FORMAT( f.SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) AND US_Id != 0  ORDER BY SC_Score DESC 
                   LIMIT 3
          ) AS u )ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) DESC, SC_Score DESC
```

Comment: you sure you need the outer query? - I might not understand the structure of MySQL queries fully, but it looks like if you add "DISTINCT" to the subquery, you do not need the outer query at all..

Comment: Even if you manage to correct the syntax this query will be extremely slow on any big table. It would be better to rewrite it completely, but you have to clarify what exactly do you want to get, possibly with some example data and expected output.

Comment: It looks rather hideous, but what are you actually looking for.  It appears there is a scores table and you want the top 3 for some given date.  But with ambiguity on which "sc_date" for your "f" alias to the inner query is unclear.  OR.. are you looking for the top 3 scores for every day available in the scores table.  So, if you have 20 days of scores, you want the top 3 of all 20 days... Totally different query required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `f.SC_Date` in the inner query like that - remember the bit in brackets will be run first, and then the bit outside will be run on the result.

You'd need to declare `scores f` inside that select statement for this to work.

I expect you don't need it at all though - something like:

```
SELECT * from   scores f
WHERE
  SC_Id IN (
          SELECT SC_Id FROM (
                  SELECT SC_Id from scores where DATE_FORMAT( SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) = DATE_FORMAT( SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) AND US_Id != 0  ORDER BY SC_Score DESC 
                   LIMIT 3
          ) AS u )ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( SC_Date, "%Y%m" ) DESC, SC_Score DESC
```

Should work, unless I'm mistaken as to your intentions here.